# Reading ISO15693 RFID tag through Android NFC results in incorrect data output

Tags: android, tags, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

We have some ISO15693 tags that we used to read using an RFID reader. Today I started working on a sample application on Android to read the same tags using `NfcV` with Android 6 (API 23).

I was able to read some data from the tag but the data has some unexpected characters. This is the code I used:

```
private void readTagData(Tag tag) throws Exception {
    byte[] id = tag.getId();
    String strTag = new String(id, "UTF-8");
    boolean techFound = false;
    for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
        if (tech.equals(NfcV.class.getName())) {
            techFound = true;
            NfcV nfcvTag = NfcV.get(tag);
            try {
                nfcvTag.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                int offset = 0;  
                int blocks = 19;  
                byte[] cmd = new byte[]{
                        (byte)0x60,                  
                        (byte)0x23,                  
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,  // placeholder for tag UID
                        (byte)(offset & 0x0ff),      
                        (byte)((blocks - 1) & 0x0ff)
                };
                System.arraycopy(id, 0, cmd, 2, 8);
                byte[] response = nfcvTag.transceive(cmd);

                response = Arrays.copyOfRange(response, 0, 96);
                String strData = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                mTextView.setText("TAG:" + strTag + " DATA:" + strData);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "An error occurred while reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                nfcvTag.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to close the connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

Tag ID (UTF-8 decoded): {��WP�

Data (UTF-8 decoded): ����1ead��1234��5678��5000��00B1��2345��6181��5064��1602��2016��1603��2016��1602��2018��0011��8899��0002��0920��16����

Data bytes in hexadecimal representation:

```
0000316561640031 3233340035363738
0035303030003030 42310032333‌43500
363138310035303‌6 3400313630320032
303‌1360031363033 0032303‌136003136
30320032303‌13800 303031310038383‌9
3900303030320030 393‌​2300031360000
```

Now part of this data is correct but I am not sure why these "�" characters are there. Tag ID is also not correct.

Separately I tried to convert the byte array 'response' and Tag ID to hex string and then to ASCII with the same result.

Comment: maybe they write it to RFID tag without using UTF-8

Comment: Definitely the old RFID application uses UTF-8 on reading Below code from old application: result = byteArray != null ? new String(byteBuf.array(), "UTF-8") : null;

Comment: try Latin-1 instead of UTF-8

Comment: The tag ID is certainly not something that you could sensibly interpret as UTF-8 string. Regarding the remaining data: Could it be that only parts of the blocks are encoded in UTF-8? Also are you sure that the data starts at block 0? You might also want to reveal the hexadecimal representation of those byte arrays to us, and, since you seem to have the code of some "old application" (one that seems to work) you miht want to reveal the relevant pieces of code (that do the actaul reading and interpretation) of that other application as well...

Comment: Ah and certainly want to remove the first byte of the reponse (which is the flags byte) to convert only the data field of the reponse into a UTF-8 string.

Comment: Yes the data starts at block 0. This is how the data is interpreted 1=Header Serial number=ead123456785 Catalog=00000B123456 and so on. The data is retrieved correctly but it has the ? character all over the place.

Comment: The hex string is equal to  (000031656164003132333400353637380035303030003030423100323334350036313831003530363400313630320032303136003136303300323031360031363032003230313800303031310038383939003030303200303932300031360000).

Comment: The old application is using ID Blue HF reader and ID Blue SDK for Android to read and write to the ISO 15693 tags. Don't have the code for it but I have some application documentation.

Comment: I installed RFID NFC Tool App from Google store on my device and read the tag. The hex string that was retrieved 31 65 61 64 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 35 30 30 30 30 30 42 31 32 33 34 35 36 31 38 31 ... etc. The '00' are not available part of the blocks read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that you receive is the expected response for the command that you send:

You send the command READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS (command code 0x23) parametrized to read 19 blocks starting at offset 0. The block size of your tag seems to be 4 bytes.

Moreover, you specify a flags byte of 0x60, which translates to the flags *Address_flag* and *Option_flag*. The *Address_flag* makes the command addressed (i.e. you have to specify the UID of the target tag, which you properly do). The *Option_flag* makes the tag return the block security status in addition to the block data itself. Consequently, the response from your tag looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-...-+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| FLAGS | BSS_0 | BLOCK_DATA_0                  | BSS_1 | BLOCK_DATA_1                  | ... | BSS_18 | BLOCK_DATA_18                 | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-...-+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The first byte, the response flags, indicate the overall outcome of the command (e.g. 0x00, as in your case, means success). Due to the *Option_flag*, each block of data is prepended with a `BSS_x` byte (the block security status), which seems to be 0x00 for all of the blocks.

Since you don't seem to be interested in the block security status, you might just as well use the command without the *Option_flag* (flags = 0x20):

```
byte[] cmd = new byte[]{
        (byte)0x20,                  
        (byte)0x23,                  
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,  // placeholder for tag UID
        (byte)(offset & 0x0ff),      
        (byte)((blocks - 1) & 0x0ff)
};
```

Then, the response will be:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-...-+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| FLAGS | BLOCK_DATA_0                  | BLOCK_DATA_1                  | ... | BLOCK_DATA_18                 | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-...-+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Consequently, in order to extract the data blocks from the response, you could then use:

```
response = Arrays.copyOfRange(response, 1, 4 * blocks);
```

Finally, decoding the tag ID into UTF-8 does not make sense at all for ISO/IEC 15693 tags. I'm not sure what value you would expect there but probably you wanted to simply convert the bytes of the ID into their hexadecimal representation.